# Workflow between two people on github

Tags: git, github

I am developing an app with my friend and we are using Github.

We are currently using the next flow of actions, but we are not sure we are doing it correctly.

Lets look at example:

Latest project resides on Github under Organisation X. Person A and person B fork project from Organisation X.
Person A makes a change and pushes changes to forked project on his Github account. Person A then creates pull request from forked project to Organisation X and merges changes.
Person B must first create pull request from forked project on his Github account to Organisation x and get latest changes. He then calls "git pull" to get changes from his account and merges them.

Constant pull requests in each direction (Organisation X -> Forked project, Forked project -> Organisation X) require a lot of clicking in Github and feels wrong. I'm almost certain we are doing something wrong and there is an easier way of collaboration.

Also, is there any good free merge tool for MAC OS X? Default FileMerge doesn't have the option to choose what to merge from each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow is up to you, but in my opinion pull requests are good for

- large teams, or
- access control.

On a small two-person team, if you trust each other's commits, there's nothing wrong with both pushing into the same repository on GitHub. No need to have your own forks, no need for pull requests.

Just make sure to have a strategy for keeping your history clean (you need this with forks and pull requests too). The definition of "clean" varies from team to team, but one popular options is to always rebase your local work on top of the latest GitHub work before pushing, e.g.

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

Other teams loathe `rebase` and strongly avoid it. It's a good idea to think about how you want to work together, and how you want your history to look. Aim for consistency.